# Sweedler Notation: limitations and left comodule version.

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

I have two questions:

1. In the nlab entry [about the sweedler notation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Sweedler+notation)  it reads "One can formalize in fact which manipulations are allowed with such a reduced notation." Has anyone done that/an idea on what kind of limitations there are? The article has no sources.
2. Given a coalgebra $(A, \Delta_A, \epsilon; k)$, $k$ unital ring and a (left) $A$-comodule $\rho^M : M \to A \otimes_k M$ one writes
   $$ \rho^M(m) = \sum\limits_{(m)} m_{(-1)} \otimes m_{(0)}. $$ Now [Hazewinkel et. al. [p. 278]](https://doi.org/10.1090/surv/168) write 
   $$ \sum\limits_{(m)} m_{(-2)} \otimes m_{(-1)} \otimes m_{(0)} := (\Delta_A \otimes M) \rho^M(m) = (M \otimes \rho^M)  \rho^M(m)  $$ for the comodule axiom (which is the rightmost equation). This can be written as 
   $$ \sum\limits_{(m),(m_{(-1)})} m_{(-1)_{(-2)}} \otimes m_{(-1)_{(-1)}} \otimes m_{(0)} = \sum\limits_{(m),(m_{(0)})}  m_{(-1)} \otimes m_{(0)_{(-1)}} \otimes m_{(0)_{(0)}} $$ 
   or $$ \sum\limits_{(m),(m_{(-1)})} m_{(-1)_{(1)}} \otimes m_{(-1)_{(2)}} \otimes m_{(0)} = \sum\limits_{(m),(m_{(0)})}  m_{(-1)} \otimes m_{(0)_{(-1)}} \otimes m_{(0)_{(0)}}, $$ where the "stacked" indices are different. I haven't found anyone doing this computation. What should I use/is the right one? On one hand, the second expression uses the established comultiplication notation for coalgebras, i.e. 
   $$ \Delta_A(a) = \sum\limits_{(a)} a_{(1)} \otimes a_{(2)}.$$ On the other hand, mixing the ordering  of positive/negative integers (sparing the 0 for comodule "elements")  and arriving at the (-2),(-1),(0) sequence suggests using the first one. Anyway, the problem obviously stems from defining the the comultiplication once, having both left and right comodules and trying to distinguesh them.

Comment: I would use the second, since the subscripts on $m_{(-1)}$ have no reason to match the ones on $m$. Either way, the notation is not as standardized and formalized as the typical undergrad-level notations are, so you can use whatever you want as long as you explain what it means.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I did some more digging and found an explicit calculation in [Hopf algebras - An introduction (2.1.5/p. 67)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1786197), in which the authors follow the second version. Anyway, your comment had swayed my opinion before, so this is just reaffirmation.